# How do I use NDSolve in Mathematica to solve a bvp by shooting method

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I have the following sets of ordinary differential equations:

$f''=g\frac{g^2+\gamma^2}{g^2+\lambda \gamma^2}$

$g'=\frac{1}{3}f'^2-\frac{2}{3}ff''+Mnf'$

$(1+Rd)\theta''+\frac{2}{3}Prf\theta'+N_{b}\theta'\phi'+N_{t}\theta'^{2}=0$

$\phi''+\frac{2}{3}Lef\phi'+\frac{N_{t}}{N_{b}}\theta''=0$

And the boundary conditions are:

$f=0,\; f'=1,\; \theta=1,\; \phi=1\; at\; \eta=0$

$ f'\rightarrow0,\; \theta\rightarrow0,\; \phi\rightarrow0\; as\; \eta\rightarrow\infty$

Please could someone show me how do I use shooting method in Mathematica to find the solutions of $f'(\eta)$, $g(\eta)$, $\theta(\eta)$, $\phi(\eta)$

I used the following code

```
ODEs[Ω1_, Ω2_, Ω3_, λ_, γ_, Mn_, Rd_, Lew_, Nb_, Nt_, Pr_] := {f''[η] == g[η]*(g[η]^2 + γ^2)/(g[η]^2 + λ*γ^2),
g'[η] == (1/3)*(f'[η])^2 - (2/3)*f[η]*f''[η] + Mn*f'[η],
θ''[η] == -(1/1 + Rd)*(2/3)*Pr*f[η]*Θ'[η] - (Nb/1 + Rd)*Θ'[η]*ϕ'[η] - (Nt/1 + Rd)*(Θ'[η])^2,
ϕ''[η] == -(2/3)*Lew*f[η]*ϕ'[η] - (Nt/Nb)*Θ''[η],
f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1, θ[0] == 1, ϕ[0] == 1, g[0] == Ω1, Θ'[0] == Ω2, ϕ'[0] = Ω3}

Soln[Ω1_, Ω2_, Ω3_, λ_, γ_, Mn_, Rd_, Lew_, Nb_, Nt_, Pr_] :=



NDSolve[ODEs[Ω1, Ω2, Ω3, λ, γ, Mn, Rd, Lew, Nb, Nt, Pr], {f, g, Θ, ϕ}, {η, 0, 10}]

EndCondition[Ω1_?NumericQ, Ω2_?NumericQ, Ω3_?NumericQ, λ_?NumericQ, γ_?NumericQ, Mn_?NumericQ, Rd_?NumericQ, Lew_?NumericQ, Nb_?NumericQ, Nt_?NumericQ, Pr_?NumericQ] :=
{(First[g[η] /. Soln[Ω1, Ω2, Ω3, λ, γ, Mn, Rd, Lew, Nb, Nt, Pr]] /. η -> 10),
(First[Θ[η] /. Soln[Ω1, Ω2, Ω3, λ, γ, Mn, Rd, Lew, Nb, Nt, Pr]] /. η -> 10),
(First[ϕ[η] /. Soln[Ω1, Ω2, Ω3, λ, γ, Mn, Rd, Lew, Nb, Nt, Pr]] /. η -> 10)}
EndCondition[0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5]
```

[This is the source from where I have based my code](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Brian_Higgins2/post/How_to_solve_a_system_of_non-Linear_ODEs_Boundary_Value_Problems_Numerically/attachment/59d63f6cc49f478072ea9a72/AS%3A273779031248912%401442285415528/download/SadiqBVP.pdf)

Comment: I used the NDSolve solver

Comment: I have added a code, please I need some guidance regarding the output